# fullcalendar parsing ISO8601 Date does not work

Tags: json, parsing, date, fullcalendar, iso8601

I'm getting a valid ISO8601 back from a JSON string, but it's not displayed correct in the fullcalendar.

creating date format with JAVA formatter:
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.sZ")
df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Berlin"))

config of calendar:

ignoreTimezone: false,
timeFormat=H:mm{ - H:mm}

JSON-Result:

```
{
    "id":1,
    "title":"Date with Chuck Norris",
    "start":"2011-12-02T09:30:00.0+0100",
    "end":"2011-12-02T10:30:00.0+0100",
    "color":"",
    "allDay":false
}
```

- take start-time 9:30 is the DB value but the +0100 is not recognized, so displayed time is 9:30, but that's wrong, must be 10:30. same for end date

...

(to get sure that it will be parsed correctly, I did another thing on config:)
eventRender: function(event, element) {
                    event.start = $.fullCalendar.parseDate(event.start); //tried also $.fullCalendar.parseISO8601()
                    event.end = $.fullCalendar.parseDate(event.end);  //tried also $.fullCalendar.parseISO8601()
}

- tried with onEventRender and parseDate() but nothing happens
- tried with onEventRender and parseISO8601() -> but nothing happens and JS-Error (see attachement: js-error.png)

using jquery 1.6.3 and latest fullcalendar 1.5.2

Thank you very much!

Cheers,

Marco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding your date format[2011-12-02T09:30:00.0+0100] means 9:30 in European/Berlin format. I tried creating the event and my system was set to GMT format and it is shown to me as 8:30 in the calendar. If you pass this format and check it in the same timezone(European/berlin),no difference will be seen.

Comment: Hey Admirer. Thx for your reply.
Okay, did I got it right. If I'm living in germany (with utc +01:00) and I'm getting a datetime-string as shown in the example with +01:00 at the end, it will happen nothing, because i'm living in a 01:00-range? that is wired!
so if I would life in a timezone with +02:00 and same json result of +01:00 it will create -1 hour = 08:30? is my understanding correct?
so in case of that, what can be a solution with fullcalendar? any suggestions? thank you very much

Comment: It should be 10:30 in(+2:00). What happens in fullcalendar is, the date object created is in clients timezone and the offset(60 minutes) is applied to the client timezone date object.So you have to keep that in mind. I think it is better to put ignoreTimeZone:true and do whatever processing in server side,so that fullcalendar just displays the given datetime.